# How can I connect a Windows 8 PC to a Samba domain

Tags: windows-8, samba, windows-domain

I am using Samba 3, and want to join my Windows 8 PC to the Samba domain.

Windows 8 cannot join out of the box, so I added the following registry entries:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
        DWORD DomainCompatibilityMode 1
        DWORD DNSNameResolutionRequired 0
```

And now it talks to the Samba server ok, however I get the following error:
[image: Samba Windows 8 error]

And I notice that the machine name created on the samba server does not match its name:

```
win-8jq3fg1n74e$:x:30003:30003:Machine:/var/lib/nobody:/bin/false
```

It is like it is using an internal name.

The following is the error in the `smb.log`

```
[2012/10/21 14:26:16.099520,  0] passdb/pdb_interface.c:348(pdb_default_create_user) _samr_create_user: Running the command `/usr/sbin/useradd  -c Machine -d /var/lib/nobody -s /bin/false win-8jq3fg1n74e$' gave 9        
[2012/10/21 14:26:28.143224,  0] lib/util_sock.c:474(read_fd_with_timeout)
[2012/10/21 14:26:28.143420,  0] lib/util_sock.c:1441(get_peer_addr_internal)
  getpeername failed. Error was Transport endpoint is not  connected
  read_fd_with_timeout: client 0.0.0.0 read error = Connection reset by peer.
```

Comment: What do you mean can't join out of the box? Are you using Windows 8 core, not Pro, or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @nhinkle I mean in the same way that Windows 7 cannot join a Samba domain out of the box - Samba3 supports NT type domains, and W7 and W8 so needs the registry settings above before you begin.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So it's an issue of backwards-compatibility then. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things I did to get this to work, though I believe the first might be all that is required:

1. It appears that while you set the machine name fairly early on in the setup, it doesn't actually take until another reboot.  So internally it is `win-xxxxxxxxxxx` until a reboot where it then takes on the machine name defined in the Computer Name dialog above.
2. Setting a primary suffix in the Computer Name dialog

With the registry settings in the OP and an additional boot (and possibly ensuring there is a suffix), joining Samba domains works fine.

Comment: I think changing the computer name while your are joining seems to be a fairly common mistake. You change the system name, reboot, then join, reboot. If you attempt to change the system name while joining a domain - it will attempt to use the old system name to join and Bad Things Will Happen (tm).

Comment: The computer name wasn't changed during joining.

Answer (score 0):

```
[2012/10/21 14:26:28.143224,  0] lib/util_sock.c:474(read_fd_with_timeout)
[2012/10/21 14:26:28.143420,  0] lib/util_sock.c:1441(get_peer_addr_internal)
```

I had the same problem. I had probably broken the relation between user and group.

I deleted user and group, created new ones, and it was OK.