# Why users of Windows 8.x can't login to our domain?

Tags: windows-8, samba, domain

We have a domain set with Samba Version 4.0.0beta2. Machines with Windows 7 and Windows XP have no problems to log in but Windows 8.x machine has this problema where the machine joins the domain but no user can after the first reboot. "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request".
What's could be wrong?

Comment: That error is usually when the PC can't find the logon server. One of the simplest thing to check is check your Network connection. If the PC has network connection, you might want to try to ping the logon server (if known)

Comment: I can add the machine to the domain, navigate the internet access the shares in the network if I log in with local user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is directly related to another one of mine:

> [Is there any trick to join and use Windows 8/8.1 with Samba 4 (4.1.6)?](https://superuser.com/questions/749052/is-there-any-trick-to-join-and-use-windows-8-8-1-with-samba-4-4-1-6)

It's happening because of wrong realm naming. Our internal DNS conflicts with the ad's realm.

For example:
my website has the external domain letsdancesamba.me and the Active Directory's realm is set to letsdancesamba.me. This is causing conflicts inside the DNS when it receives requests for joins, logins etc. Windows 8.x and Linux clients are having more problems than Windows 7 and the older machines with Windows XP.

If you have a external site like letsdancesamba.meit seams to be wrong:

```
samba-tool domain provision --realm=**letsdancesamba.me** --domain=letsdancesamba
```

instead should be something like:

```
samba-tool domain provision --realm=ad.letsdancesamba.me --domain=letsdancesamba
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = letsdancesamba
realm = ad.letsdancesamba.me
netbios name = SHARES
dns forwarder = <one of your choice>
server role = active directory domain controller
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the systems attempting to logon to the domain have not been added to the domain. I've seen this error before when a computer is either removed from the domain or the system is not part of the domain and it is attempting to authenticate and join.

Comment: I can see the machine listed on the domain.

Comment: When you say you can see the machine listed on the domain, where exactly are you seeing the machine name? Are you able to search for the machine name via Active Directory?

Comment: I can see using the dsa.msc

Comment: Perhaps this reference will help you out. It seems like a similar question has been asked before and there are some things to try.

http://superuser.com/questions/490453/how-can-i-connect-a-windows-8-pc-to-a-samba-domain?rq=1

Comment: I've noticed that if I use Samba 4 from the apt package manager I can´t get it to work fine, but if I compile samba source it works better and it, oddly, seems easier to setup.

Comment: This problem is directly related to this one: http://superuser.com/questions/749052/is-there-any-trick-to-join-and-use-windows-8-8-1-with-samba-4-4-1-6
It's happening because problems in realm naming. Our internal DNS conflicts with the ad's realm.