# Is there any trick to join and use Windows 8/8.1 with Samba 4 (4.1.6)?

Tags: windows-8, samba, active-directory

It seems that Samba doesn't like me at all. I've followed various tutorials and I can't get Windows 8 to work properly with a Ubuntu Server as domain controller. This week i've downloaded ubuntu 14.04 lts and set a fast domain configuration. As usual all other Windows version (XP and 7) work but the newest M$ nightmare doesn't. In this try it doesn't even join the domain, keeps saying the my username or password are wrong.

My /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        realm = DOMAIN.LAN
        netbios name = DOM
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/domain.lan/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[test]
        path = /SHARES/test
        read only = no
```

Does anyone have a tutorial that really works? Because I've tried many, each one with different configurations that works only with the people that made them.

And is there a way to import my old AD users, computers and ID in a way that I won't need to rejoin all computers?

[Edit]

Now I've tested various versions since 4.0.0 (final version) to 4.1.9, all working with Windows 8.1.

Make sure that **acl** and **attr** are installed and are set in the **/etc/fstab** file:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/dev/sda1 /               ext4    user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Remount using:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

I also add the **wins** option to the **/etc/nsswitch.conf** file:

```
hosts:          files wins dns
```

Provisioning a domain with:

```
$ samba-tool domain provision --domain=domain --adminpass=Abc12345 --server-role=dc --realm=domain.lan --dns-backend=SAMBA_INTERNAL
```

The /etc/samba/smb.conf:

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = DOMAIN
    realm = DOMAIN.LAN
    netbios name = DOM
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/domain.lan/scripts
    read only = No

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
```

Setting the complete name in **/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.1.1 dom
192.168.0.2 dom.domain.lan dom
```

and /etc/hostname:

```
dom.domain.lan
```

Setting the static IP address:

```
auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.2
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 broadcast 192.168.0.255
 gateway 192.168.0.1
 dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222
 dns-search domain.lan
```

and copying the generated /var/lib/samba/private/krb5.conf to /etc

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Linux-with-Windows-8 Help any?

Comment: Thank you techie007, but I've already tried that. :(

Comment: Thanks for this follow up, i will try this out tomorrow at work. Possibly mark this as solved?

Comment: It is working on my new "provisioned" domains, but the old one continues to present problems with Windows 8.x and I am having problems exporting/importing the users, groups and machines using various methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my test with different version worked. Even the beta versions including the 4.0.0beta2.
I manage to upgrade to version 4.1.11 from Debian backports without breaking the system (phew). Solved some problems but not Windows 8/8.1 joins. So tests after tests we found the problem.

The reason that worked on my tests is that I used **only the IP address of the samba server as DNS on the VMs**.
On the production network we have a primary and a secondary DNS this is causing the problem because of the realm.
Windows 8/81 have no problem to join the domain if we use only the samba server IP as DNS. This causes a problem were we can not navigate to internal pages/services like intranet and some internal systems.

Now the problem is bigger, nothing to do with Windows 8/8,1. We'll have to change the realm name.

If you have a external site like mysite.com it seams to be wrong:

```
samba-tool domain provision --realm=**mysite.com** --domain=mysite
```

instead should be something like:

```
samba-tool domain provision --realm=ad.mysite.com --domain=mysite
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = MYSITE
realm = ad.mysite.com
netbios name = SHARES
dns forwarder = <one of your choice>
server role = active directory domain controller
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no version issue with Samba, ensure that your clocks are within the allowable threshold. Time has caused me this exact same issue a number of times. With 4.1.7 my 8 and now 8.1 machine was able to join and login.

looking deeper at your config, the realm could be the issue.

> There is a problem with Windows 8, where Microsoft raises new domain name policy. When a domain contain a dot (".") in its name (ie. example.com), Windows 8 treat this name as a Active Directory name and is trying to contact Kerberos/LDAP server even there is none. So this is impossible to join this domain and there is no known fix or workaround yet.

Source: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Registry_changes_for_NT4-style_domains#Windows_8_and_classic_domain_.28NT-4_style.29_with_a_dot_in_its_name

Comment: Kind of late. Actually I've done tests with various versions 4.0.0, 4.0.19, 4.1.0, 4.1.6, 4.1.7 and now 4.1.9. Did tests with 4.0.x betas found no problem, but, all my tests with exception of 2 or 3 I used SAMBA_INTERNAL backend instead of BIND for DNS. None of my test presented problems like we have with the 4.0.0beta2.

Comment: What I need now is a safe way of exporting machines, users to a new server with some different configurations. pdbedit exports but have problems importing, samba_backup script the service doesn't start after restoring the files and following the procedures before starting it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now: I started the samba manually with debug option an found that because of time deviation between client and server the password match failed(Kerberos ticket expired).
After fixing the time difference the client joins domain (even with samba 4.1.6)...